# Fixed padding between the bars in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

We have an issue regarding fixed padding between the bars in Highcharts
Problem: When we set the values of "pointPadding" and "pointWith", it change the pointPadding in relation to how many items we have.
Goal/What we want: That the padding should be an exact value no matter how many items (rows) we have.

In the image you can see the results today, not what we want!

[image]

Any suggestions?

We add some example how the code looks right now.

```
const table = {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: [{
    categories: xAxisCategories,
    reversed: false,
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    allowDecimals: false,
    reversed: false,
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    title: undefined,
    tickInterval: 1
  },
  {
    allowDecimals: false,
    reversed: false,
    opposite: true,
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    title: undefined,
    tickInterval: 1
  }
  ],
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      groupPadding: 0.1,
      pointPadding: 15,
      grouping: false,
      shadow: false,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: "black",
        x: -50
      }
    },
  },
  series: [{
    pointWidth: 35,
    pointPadding: 0.5,
    showInLegend: false,
    data: dataSeries,
    animation: {
      duration: 1000
    }
  }],
  title: {
    text: `${user.user.name} - ${theRelation}`,
    align: 'left',
    x: 40,
    style: {
      color: '#BBBBC9',
      fontSize: 12,
      XfontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `load` event and adapt chart's height to the amount of points and padding constant.

```
const adaptPadding = ({target: chart}) => {
    const padding = 20;
    const pointWidth = 35;
    const plotHeight = (chart.xAxis[0].max + 1) * padding + (chart.xAxis[0].max + 1) * pointWidth;

    chart.setSize(
        null,
        plotHeight + chart.chartHeight - chart.plotHeight,
        false
    );
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: adaptPadding
        }
    },
    ...
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: adaptPadding
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/16fogv07/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setSize

Comment: nice, clean and neat. Thanks for this!